# libreoffice can not be removed completely

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

I am using ubuntu12.04 and the xfce4.6.

Now I remove the `libreoffice` through the `Ubuntu Software Center`,however it seems that it is not removed completely.

Since I can find the `libreoffice` item at the menu `Application-Office-LIbreOffice`,also I can run the `libreoffice` command in the terminal. Both of them can start up the `libreoffice`,however this is the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the `Text Document` `Drawing` and etc are not available.

What is the problem?

Comment: Find out what you still have installed with: `dpkg -l '*libreoffice*' | grep ii`. It is probably `libreoffice-core` or `-common`.

Comment: Thanks for you guys, it is removed completely following the link by Eliah Kagan. Thanks.

Comment: just run  > sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-*